# Lumen define table name does not work

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a database that couple of people use. So it happens that I changed the name of classes but the table is called the same. So what I use is :

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'fota_devices';
}
```

But I am getting error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database-fota.devices' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `devices` where ....)

It looks like the table name does not get assigned.
I tried to `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.
Still does not work.

EDIT: Controller code

```
class DeviceController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request) {
    $i = 1;
    $data_array = json_decode($request->data,true);
    foreach ($data_array as $data) {
        $validator =Validator ::make($data,[
            ..
            ]
        );

        if (! $validator->fails()) {
            $device = new Device;
            $device->create([
            ...
            ]);
            $response[$i]['status'] = "Success";
        }
        else {
            $response[$i]['status'] = "Failed";
            $response[$i]["errors"] = $validator->errors()->all();
        }
        $response[$i]['data'] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
    return new Response(200);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the actual table name?

Comment: @Option `fota_devices` but it is looking for `devices` as the class name.

Comment: Is this on locahost or a server, are you running artisan serve?

Comment: Can you also add the controller that's using this logic

Comment: @Option Added the controller code and  my project is in remote server and I use localhost as database

Comment: @zerociudo Once you check your model inside table name and your MySQL database in table name are same or different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you check your model inside table name and your MySQL database in table name are same or different.Because your model in tabel name is like below and whenever you run the query table name are diffrent like below.

```
protected $table = 'fota_devices';


Query :- select count(*) as aggregate from devices where ....)
```

Above both table are diffrent.

Your both table name are diffrent **fota_devices** and **devices**.